# Find all derangements for $n=4$ and $n=5$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find all derangements for $n=4$ and $n=5$

**Solution for $n=4$**

I know there are 9 possibilities

$(2,1,4,3), (2,3,4,1), (2,4,1,3), (3,1,4,2),(3,4,1,2), (3,4,2,1) (4,1,2,3),(4,3,1,2), (4,3,2,1)$

**Solution for $n=5$**

**I know there are 44 of them, I am wondering if someone had a link to a list of them, or possibly a program that would spit them out, or could help me in general, thanks!**

Comment: Here is a C++ code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369941/how-to-generate-permutations-where-ai-i

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar you are wrong, the formula you gave is for permutations, not derangements.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Please read the question again. OP isn't asking arrangements, he/she is asking **De**arrangements.

Comment: I cannot imagine this being the intended exercise for a purely mathematics based class in combinatorics.  The more interesting question to us would be simply "how many" there are.  If the exercise truly is to list them all out, that is incredibly tedious and suggests that the intended solution is to write a program.  Just start with one that cycles through the permutations, then check to see if it is a derangement and list it if it is.  There are only $5!=120$ permutations, which is not that many, so the efficiency won't matter too much.

Comment: That's Right...!

Comment: I would, for instance, never ask someone in a mathematics class "*Write out all of the numbers from $1$ to $50$*."  I would see that as being too tedious as well, even with it being at a much lower level of understanding required.

Comment: unforuntately this is what I have been asked to do

Comment: @JMoravitz Listing $n=3$ or at most $n=4$ seems fine, but $n=5$ is clearly stupid

Comment: @user123 Are you sure you're not asked to write a program ?

Comment: yes unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of things are actually really easy to find with Constraint programming.

For a permutation of length n we got the following constraints for a list:
- The list has to have length(n)
- Any number x must be in range 1..n
- All elements must different

Looking at a derangement of length n we got the following constraints:
- Be a permutation
- Have no fixed points

We can put all of this quite fast together in Prolog with:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

permut(L,N) :-
    length(L, N),
    L ins 1..N,
    all_different(L),
    label(L).

noFixpoint([],_Xs).
noFixpoint([X|Xs],N1) :-
    X #\= N,
    N1 #= N-1,
    noFixpoint(Xs,N).   

derangement(L,N) :-
    permut(L,N),
    noFixpoint(L,0).

findDerangements(N,Ls) :-
    findall(L,derangement(L,N),Ls).
```

With derangement(L,N) we can now simply generate derangements of a certain a size or all of them (of a certain size) with findDerangements(N,Ls).

```
 findDerangements(4,Ls), length(Ls,N).
 Ls = [[2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2|...], [4, 1|...], [4|...], [...|...]],
 N = 9.

 ?- findDerangements(5,Ls), length(Ls,N).
 Ls = [[2, 1, 4, 5, 3], [2, 1, 5, 3, 4], [2, 3, 1, 5, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 1], [2, 3, 5, 1|...], [2, 4, 1|...], [2, 4|...], [2|...], [...|...]|...],
 N = 44.
```

You can try it out here [ideone link - source](https://ideone.com/GFRKWk)

Comment: thanks so much for creating a code for the derangements of 5!

Answer (score 0):

None of the derangements can start with $1$.

They can start with $2$, so let's find some of those.

The next digit can be $1$. (We're left with $3,4,5$.)

The third digit can't be $3$, but it can be $4$. The fourth digit can be $3$.

However, the last digit can't be $5$, so go back a place and put the $5$ there. The $3$ can be put in the last place.

So we have $21453$ as the first derangement.

Replace the $4$ with a $5$. Then, $3$ works in the fourth place, and $4$ works in the fifth.

So we have $21534$ as the next derangement.

Replacing the $3$ with $4$ doesn't work.

Next, let's try $23...$ We can put $1$ in the third place. $4$ doesn't work in the fourth place, but $5$ does. $4$ works in the last place.

So we have $23154$ as the next derangement.

Next, to $234..$ Both $1$ and $5$ can work in the fourth place, but $5$ does not work in the last place.

So we have $23451$ as the next derangement.

Next, to $235..$ Now, $1$ works in the fourth place, but $4$ does not. $1$ works in the last place.

So we have $23514$ as the next derangement.

And so on. Just find them like this smallest to largest.